# Elastic Search Upgrade in Ruby On Rails from 0.90 to 2.x

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, rubygems, elasticsearch-rails

In My current Ruby on Rails application elasticsearch is implememnted, the version of elasticsearch is **0.90** and we used "**tire**" gem.

Now I want to update it with latest version of elasticsearch("2.x").

Tier gem is now not supporting elasticsearch version 1.x/2.x, They are suggesting to use "elasticsearch-rails" gem but how to migrate my application from old to new by using this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, beside the obvious modification in `Gemfile` and bundle, you'll  have to modify your models for starters:

I suggest you check the [ES-rails GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails): the ReadMe is very well documented.

The general idea is to include

```rb
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
```

in each of your models and then use ElasticSearch DSL as much as possible.

The point if you want to index your model in a different form from source code (i.e. public properties) is to create a `def as_indexed_json()` that will be used by ES when indexing.

Everything is (also) well documented in the [ES-model GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)

(WARNING: the 'main' elasticsearch-rails repo contains the 3 gem repos so you'll have to navigate inside repo tree to find the ReadMe file that suits you !)

If you detail a bit more your needs, we might be able to help you more !